# Update Text of ListBoxItem WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

In my project, when the user clicks the "Save Changes" button it fires an event which updates the name of the person that they are editing. 
I've been able to successfully implement this code in windows forms:

```
listBoxNames.SelectedItems[0].Text = forenameTxtBox.Text + " " +
                                      surnameTxtBox.Text;
```

But in WPF, `listBoxNames.SelectedItems[0]` doesn't have a property of 'text'.

Is there any way around this so that I can edit the text of the `ListBoxItem` in turn updating the `ListBox` with the new name? Or would I have to an `ObservableCollection<string>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Typecast selectedItem to actual object instance and edit its property instead.**

Assuming class is `Person` with `Name` property in it. It will be like this:

```
((Person)listBoxNames.SelectedItems[0]).Name = forenameTxtBox.Text + " " + 
                                                surnameTxtBox.Text;
```

Also in case you want to update UI on any property change, Person class should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Read this article [how to implement INPC on class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

---

Assuming you are simply binding to list of strings, you can update it like this:

```
listBoxNames.Items[listBoxNames.SelectedIndex] = forenameTxtBox.Text + " " + 
                                                    surnameTxtBox.Text;
```

Comment: But this way the text/content of that ListItem wouldn't update in the UI and it doesn't when I add this to my code.

Comment: Person class should implement `INPC`. Have you done that? Refer to the link posted in answer if it's new to you.

Comment: If I were to implement `INPC` I would still need to change the 'Text' property of the list item on `PropertyChanged` which brings me back to my original question of how I would do that?

Comment: I am not sure that how you are populating listbox. However, i have added another approach in case its mere string. Check updated answer.